# CSS Circle Behind Image Taking Up Full Container Width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a circle behind a logo using CSS but struggling as it keeps taking up the whole width of the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/leelawtondesign/hfqk6a0g/5/#&togetherjs=HAg4AK4vSo

[This is how it looks...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZFjK.png)

[This is how it is meant to look...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2HqO.png)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 my-auto order-2 order-md-1">
      <div class="pt-5 pt-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class=""></div>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook btn-rounded mx-2"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></button></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter btn-rounded mx-2"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-instagram btn-rounded mx-2"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></button></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2 logo d-flex position-relative">
      <img class="pt-3 pt-md-5 pb-4 pb-md-5 m-auto align-content-center" src="img/safety_first_logo.png">
    </div>


    <div class="pt-3 pt-md-0 col-12 col-md-3 text-right my-auto order-3 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
      <i class="fas fa-phone px-2"></i> <a href="tel:07481755545">07460162247</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add code to js fiddler?

Comment: Could we see your CSS? You may have it set to 100% width.

Comment: Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/leelawtondesign/hfqk6a0g/5/#&togetherjs=HAg4AK4vSo

Comment: Your fiddle lacks the required stylesheets so currently we won't be able to tell what is causing the problem. Could you add the relevant stylesheets as well?